# Fullcalendar with disabled periods for drag'n'drop

Tags: fullcalendar

How can I configure [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io) with some periods disabled for drag'n'drop. For example I need to disable

- from 2016-07-03 to 2016-07-07
- from 2016-07-10 to 2016-07-15
- from 2016-07-24 to 2016-07-26

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. Create three events spanning from 2016-07-03 to 2016-07-07 etc. Use eventOverlap: to set a function that would prohibit events to overlap with these events.

Option 2. Create several events spanning all the *permitted* time. All the events must have the same ID - this is important. Then use eventConstraint with the event ID. This way, any user event must be fully contained within your dummy event, otherwise drag&drop will fail.

Option 3. Possibly the most reasonable solution. Use eventDrop and eventResize handlers to verify that the new event's start and end meet your constraints. If not, then call revertFunc() to return the events to their original state.

Example:

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

    if (event.start.isAfter('2016-07-03') && 
         event.start.isBefore('2016-07-07') { //also add check for event.end
             revertFunc();
         }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for these ideas.
Option 3 is good and simple case but it doesn't reflect that date is disabled until user drops event. How can I hide auxiliary events in Option 1 and Option 2?